# PowerPC version of Ubuntu 10.10 or 10.04 wont boot on my Mac

Tags: installation, mac, ppc

Startup Disk does not see it as bootable.  Holding down C gives up and ejects it.  I have tried PPC version of CDs for both Lucid and Maverick.
The machine is a 867 MHz PowerPC G4 with 512 MB RAM.
I Got the ISOs [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ports/releases/lucid/release) and  [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ports/releases/maverick/release)
Any suggestions?

Comment: What program did you use to create the image? Could you try to do the same but with a USB-stick?

Answer (score 1):

Boot to OpenFirmware, then boot the CD from there.

https://help.ubuntu.com/11.10/installation-guide/powerpc/ch05s01.html

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore. What do you mean by "boot to open firmware"?! I don't recall seeing any such option on my iMac...

Answer (score 0):

I find that my G4 PPC won't boot from CDROM/DVD, in fact it's pretty fussy about reading a lot of newer optical media.

The easiest is to create a bootable USB stick. This will involve a having to boot it from the OpenFirmware prompt. There is a [good guide](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-780320.html) available.